# SQL return a decimal when dividing a INT by DATEDIFF

Tags: sql, sql-server, datediff

[Units] is col 1

[Units Sold or Let/week] is Units/DATEDIFF (col 3)

It returns a whole numbers. But if it takes 12 weeks to let 15 units, I want col 3 to return 1.25. It currently returns 1. (highlighted in image output below)

code for column 1,2,3:

```
,Units.Units
,DATEDIFF(week, StartofSales.[Start of Sales/Letting Revised],EndofSales.[End of Sales/Letting Revised])[Weeks Period]
,Units.Units/case when DATEDIFF(week, StartofSales.[Start of Sales/Letting Revised],EndofSales.[End of Sales/Letting Revised])= 0 then 1 else DATEDIFF(week, StartofSales.[Start of Sales/Letting Revised],EndofSales.[End of Sales/Letting Revised]) end as[Units/week]
```

Image
[image]

Comment: I added the SQL Server tag based on the syntax.

Comment: Those aren't the ACTUAL database table's column names, are they?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just multiply by 1.0:

```
Units.Units * 1.0 / DATEDIFF(week, StartofSales.[Start of Sales/Letting Revised],EndofSales.[End of Sales/Letting Revised])
```

This converts the value to a numeric so the division has decimal places.

Comment: Don't store numeric values as strings.  I have no idea what column is causing that problem.  This addresses the question that you have asked here.

Comment: @DasalKalubowila . . . That is pretty much impossible.  It is a constant and has nothing to do with conversion from a string to a number.  Your problem is that some other column is stored as a string, when it should be a number.  However, if you can reproduce this, put an example in DB Fiddle or a similar tool.